# Android Intent is null for ACTION_VIEW a YouTube url, even with Chrome and YouTube installed

Tags: android, android-intent

I have a Help menu in my Android app that will show either a help web page or a help video. We've had some weird problems over time with the Intent coming back null because they don't have a browser or something like that (at least that has previously been my assumption based on Firebase exception reporting). So we made the code a little more complicated to check for any apps for the YouTube video url put together in a couple different ways. Trying to build the Intent differently if the system says no apps can handle it.

It's finally happening to me though, so that's good! However, I've got Chrome and the YouTube app installed on my phone but the resolveActivity() is coming back as null.

In the code below, `youtubeuri = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHb9wYcmQcg"` and also `videourlstring = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JHb9wYcmQcg"` (this particular case, the urls end up being the same thing).

But even though I have both Chrome and YouTube installed, it can't find an activity to start the Intent for a basic `ACTION_VIEW` for a YouTube url.

Did something change in a recent version of AndroidOS and the way I'm doing it doesn't work anymore without special permissions or something? What am I doing wrong?

```
private void startVideo(HelpTutorial tutorial) {

    String videoid = tutorial.getVideoID();
    Uri youtubeuri = Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + videoid);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, youtubeuri);

    List<ResolveInfo> list = this.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    if (list.size() == 0) {
        String videourlstring = tutorial.getVideoURLString();
        intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(videourlstring));
    }
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        AlertDialogFragment alert = new AlertDialogFragment();
        alert.setTitle(getString(R.string.no_browser_installed_title));
        alert.setMessage(getString(R.string.no_browser_installed_message));
        alert.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "No Browser Error");
    }
    
}
```

EDIT:

If I just `startActivity()` even though `resolveActivity()` returned null, the YouTube app is actually opened. So the app is installed and works... but for some reason my app is not allowed to see that.

Comment: Do you have the proper manifest stuff to declare your package visibility needs?

Comment: @CommonsWare Unlikely. I don't remember having to do anything like that. I was under the impression that the only Manifest stuff would need to be on the YouTube/Chrome side to declare that they handle ACTION_VIEW intents. This code has been in place for a long time with only one update to try to resolve the problem finding an Activity, so it's very likely to be out of date. Can you direct me to the right place in the docs or give me the right keywords to search for? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android 11 introduced "package visibility", for privacy/security. If you use those sorts of `PackageManager` calls, you need to [add stuff to your manifest to declare what you're looking for](https://developer.android.com/training/package-visibility/declaring).

In your case, you might be able to use:

```xml
    <queries>
        <intent>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent>
    </queries>
```